# Literals and implicit narrowing conversions

Tags: c#, .net, clr

a) Shouldn’t the following assignment cause an error, since number 100 is a literal of type *int* and since compiler doesn’t allow implicit narrowing conversions?

```
byte b = 100;
```

b) If compiler doesn’t complain about implicit narrowing conversion from *int literal* to *type byte*, then why doesn’t it also allow an implicit narrowing conversion from *double literal* to *type float* ( I realize we could avoid this error by specifying float literal using F/f suffix  )?

```
byte b=16; //OK
float f1=16.9; //error
```

thank you

Comment: The rules regarding floating-point conversion are backward, but they are what they are.  There's no good reason why `float f = (float)(1.0 / 10.0);` should require a typecast (`f` will hold the most precise representation of 0.1 possible for its type), but `double d = 1.0f / 10.0f;` will compile without a warning even though the value assigned to `d` is (with regard to the precision of a double) nowhere near 0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in section 6.1.8 of the C# language spec.  It is legal for constant expressions of type int to be converted to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint or ulong provided the value is within the range of the target type.  It is fairly easy for the C# compiler to determine if the value is within the appropriate range and hence allow the conversion.

As for the double case, the C# lang spec does not specifically call out why this is not allowed.  My guess is it has to do with difficulties in determining if the double value can fit within the float value.  Getting floating point precision correct is a very difficult task and probably so much so it wasn't deemed to be worth the cost (if it was possible at all)