# Why do some narrowing conversions involving literals not require CType?

Tags: vb.net

The Double type narrows to example, which is a class. I don't want it to contain some Double values. NaN is an example of a value I don't want. The compiler doesn't complain about the literal assignment in TestMe. Why not? It does give the "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'example'" error if a *variable* typed as Double is used, but not with constants or literals.

```
Option Strict On

Public Class example

   Private d As Double

   Public Shared Sub TestMe()
      Dim x As example

      x = Double.NaN

   End Sub

   Public Sub New(d As Double)
      If Double.IsNaN(d) Then
         Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
      End If
      Me.d = d
   End Sub

   Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(value As Double) As example
      Return New example(value)
   End Operator

End Class
```

Note that this is just a trivial example to illustrate my curiosity about the compiler's behavior.

[This C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217894/literals-and-implicit-narrowing-conversions) asks a similar thing, though the compiler's behavior there is fairly straightforward and the example doesn't involve operator overloading. Then again, the VB compiler does not allow either of the following literal assignments, so why should it allow the one in my example?

```
Dim i As Integer

i = 4.0#
i = UInt32.MaxValue
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. This works. It throws an exception if you try to assign `Double.NaN`: `Dim example As example = Double.NaN`. I also don't understand why the compiler should complain about asssigning `x = Double.NaN`.

Comment: It will throw an exception at run time, true, but the question is about the compiler. The compiler should complain, IMO, because it's a narrowing conversion and option strict is on.

Comment: Sorry, i was confusing `x` and `n`. But the constructor  also throws the exception at runtime at `Dim x As example = Double.NaN`. Narrowing conversion is done at runtime.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I grant you that narrowing conversion is done at runtime, but that's beside the point. This is a question about the *compiler*, which is not supposed to allow implicit narrowing conversions to be coded when `Option Strict On` is specified. I should be getting an "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from..." as I would with any other implicit narrowing conversion like `Dim i As Integer = 4.0#`, for example. I should be able to code `Dim n As example(Double.NaN)` but I should not be able to code `Dim n As example = Double.NaN`.